# Changing file permissions, hyperlinks & notifications: How to force update

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions

I have a shared spreadsheet with hyperlinks to images saved in Drive. When passing over the links, users see the images in which they have permission and do not see them in those without it.

The problem comes when I change the permissions, either giving permission or removing it. For between 3 and 5 minutes the changes are not appreciated in spreadsheet unless the user refresh the entire page or tries to open the image, which causes them to be updated instantly.

Is there any way to force this update via apps scrips? Editing something on the sheet, updating the entire page by another user or opening other images has no effect.

A 'dirty' way to do it is by creating a copy of the image (which would have another Id) and replacing the url of the hyperlink with the url of the copy, with its new permissions, but that takes some execution time.

I attached the code with which I add and remove permissions via DriveApp and via Drive (I don't know why remove using Drive has an Error)

It also includes 'dirty' code: how to get the hyperlink url, get the file and folder IDs, the creation of the copy and deletion of the original, add new permissions, and the assignment of the new url to the hyperlink. Maybe someone can point me to a more efficient way to do this (if updating permissions is not possible).

Thanks!

```
function addPermission(fileId){  // to add permission to read file (image file in my case)
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  var usu = 'user@gmail.com';
  file.addViewer(usu);
};

function delPermission(fileId){  // to remove permission
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  var usu = 'user@gmail.com';
  file.removeViewer(usu);
};


function addPermissionWithoutMail(fileId) {  // to add permission to read file WITHOUT notification
  //value = email; type: "user", "group", "domain" or "default"; role: "owner", "writer" or "reader".
  var usu = 'user@gmail.com';
  var request = Drive.Permissions.insert({  // in 'Services' (on the left, under Libraries), add 'Drive API'
    'value': usu,
    'type': 'user',
    'role': 'reader'
  },
  fileId,
  {
    'sendNotificationEmails': false
  });
};

function delPermissionDrive(fileId){  // this function Not work. WHY??
  var permissionId2 = 'user@gmail.com'; //using the same email than addPermissionWithoutMail
  Drive.Permissions.remove(fileId,permissionId2); // ERROR: Permission not found: user@gmail.com
};



function changeImageLink(){          //  LAUNCH to change image associated with the hyperlink  **********
  
  var link = getUrlFromA1Link(); // get the url from hyperlink in a cell
  var Ids = getIDsFileFolder(link); // get Ids of file and folder of the link
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(Ids[0]); // create a variable of file 
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(Ids[1]); // create a variable of folder
  var newFileId = copyAndDelete(file,folder); // make a copy (with different Id) and delete original file 
  addPermissionWithoutMail(newFileId);// to add permission to read file (image file in my case)
  newLink(newFileId); // change url in hyperlink

};

function getUrlFromA1Link(){ // get the url from hyperlink in range A1
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1');
  var hype = range.getRichTextValue();
  var link = hype.getLinkUrl();

  return link;
};

function getIDsFileFolder(link){ // get Ids of file and folder of the link
  var IdFileArray = link.match(/[-\w]{25,}/); //extract Id file
  var IdFile = IdFileArray[0];
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(IdFile);
  var fileParents = file.getParents();
  while ( fileParents.hasNext() ) {
    var folder = fileParents.next();
    var IdFolder = folder.getId();
    //var nameFolder = folder.getName(); // to test is is correct folder
    break;  //only one parent is needed
  }
  var filfol = [IdFile, IdFolder];
  return filfol;    
};

function copyAndDelete(file,folder){ // make a copy (with different Id) and delete original file 
var newfile=file.makeCopy(file.getName()); //new file: the same name but different ID
folder.addFile(newfile);
folder.removeFile(file);
var IdFileNew = newfile.getId();
return IdFileNew;
};


function newLink(fileId){  // change url in hyperlink
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange('A1');
var link ='http://drive.google.com/uc?id=' + fileId;
var richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
    .setText('Link for Image')
    .setLinkUrl(link)
    .build();
range.setRichTextValue(richText );
};
```

Comment: You could install a time based trigger, to check every minute and do the routine for example.

Comment: The problem is that I do not know how to update permissions for user opened share sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You will always have some propagation delay. A more efficient way could be to create a web app, and display personalized content to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try `getIdForEmail` to get permission id.

```js
var permissionId2 = Drive.Permissions.getIdForEmail( 'user@gmail.com' ).id;
```